# Validation error messages messing all `float`layout

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working atm in a web which have lots of forms pages. In this screenshot you can see one of those pages:
[image]

The layout is basic. There is a container for every element group, and these containers are floating left. This image is one of the "simple" ones with containers `33% width` and just one at `66%`, however in many others pages there are many `width`combinations. It's also responsive changing the widths at a `media query breakpoint`

Every container has a `span`an `input`and a `validation error span`with display:none;

To make an example to replicate my problem I have made this simple html:

```
<div class="container padding">
    <span>name:</span>
    <input type="text"/>
    <span class="error">validation error</span>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <span>name:</span>
    <input type="text"/>
    <span class="error">validation error</span>
</div>
<div class="container padding">
    <span>name:</span>
    <input type="text"/>
    <span class="error visible">validation error</span>
</div>
<div class="container ">
    <span>name:</span>
    <input type="text"/>
    <span class="error ">validation error</span>
</div>
<div class="container padding">
    <span>name:</span>
    <input type="text"/>
    <span class="error">validation error</span>
</div>
<div class="container ">
    <span>name:</span>
    <input type="text"/>
    <span class="error">validation error</span>
</div>
```

The problem is that I can't give any more `margin-bottom`to this containers as the client have specifially asked to avoid as much as posible vertical scroll in the pages and he doesn't care if everything is very "compact" so basically when I get a validation error msg, if the container is at the left of page, it will mess all the rest of the containers as they will change position to adjust to the new container height.

In this **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/180r5ukz/3/)** You may see better what my problem is as english is not my first lenguaje. There's a commented class:

```
/*.visible {display:inline;}*/
```

when you "uncomment" it you will replicate my problem. (you can also see an image of the real form with the validation errors **[here](http://zimasolutions.com/Images/IMAGENESBORRAR/form2.jpg)**)

I can't use `position:absolute` on this span, there's just not enough room to show the message. What I have been trying to do for ages is that if I have a validation error on a left container all the containers below moves as if it were on a right container (like in this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/180r5ukz/4/)**)

I don't think this can be done just with `css`so any `jquery` solution will be greetly apreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry--I know this is ugly, but perhaps you could work with something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/180r5ukz/6/). You'd have to keep text in the error span at all times, or you could just set an explicit height on it (maybe a min-height).

```
.container.visible-error+.container:not(.padding) .error {
    display: inline;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.container+.container.visible-error:not(.padding) .error {
    visibility: visible;
}
.container.visible-error .error {
    display:inline;
}
```

Comment: That't won't solve my problem, mate. The point is that actually there's not enough room for the validation msg and I can't change that... Distances are set and aproved by the client. all the containers have to move down IF a msg is shown (not to be place already getting the html flow space. With your idea I would have to separate too much the containers and on many pages we will get vertical scroll that it's what we are trying to avoid at all costs). ty anyway for your time

Comment: I may be misunderstanding you, but did you click the link to see it in JSFiddle? With those styles, the horizontal space is only preserved when there's an existing error message. Where there's no error message on the line (as on the 5th row), it doesn't reserve any space for it.

With that said, the existing styles still need work, because when I look at it in Firefox, the two column layout isn't working. In Chrome and IE, it's two column and (from what I can tell based upon your explanation) presents in the way that you described.

Comment: I did saw your jsfiddle but basically, when the button is clicked the errors will spawn when an input is not filled... True that I missunderstood a bit your answer but You added the class `visible-error` when you want to see the msg  this may require programming to add that class to the container when "x" is happening. Current validator errors are made by default under MVC4. I was looking for a solution with css if posible (or with some simple jquery).

Comment: Anyway and again, ty. If there's no any easier way to do it I will ask my programmers mate the viability to try this out tomorrow morning and mark your answer as valid.

Comment: Well. at the end, even if more work as I have to add html to every single page, I have decide to use `divs`between rows of containers with `clear:both` (and `display:none` when media query breakpoint when the containers have to re-aling).  This way it doesn't need any javascript to make it work. Anyway I apreacite your time and I'm marking your answer as valid.